# testing Jersey endpoints with Jetty servlet container failing without sessions

Tags: java, servlets, junit, jersey, jetty

I am using embedded Jetty with Jersey. I have an authfilter for some resources, based on sessions.

When I try to test my application, JerseyTest loads I think only Jetty without servlets because the injected @Context
    HttpServletRequest httpRequest; is null.

Any ideas how to change maybe something here:

```
@Override
protected TestContainerFactory getTestContainerFactory() {
JettyTestContainerFactory j= new JettyTestContainerFactory();
return j;
}
```

or

```
@Override
protected Application configure() {
ResourceConfig r = new ResourceConfig();
r.packages("com.server.rest.jersey");
return r;
}
```

here?

Other solution is to register everything in the test without the filter, but  that's not a good integration test..

one other option is to use jersey external provider and just fire up my normal configuration. this makes the tests with the production code very tightly coupled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that can be done to my current knowledge is to have a class that starts up a Jetty server, have Jersey with the external provider configurated and in the end of the integration tests shutdown the server.